# Select a substring of X where substring of X equals a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to return to the data that I need with the SQL queries I have currently tried.

The closest I have got to is the SQL below

`SELECT SUBSTRING(path, Y + 1, 200) FROM lookup 
 WHERE (SELECT SUBSTRING(path, Y, 1) FROM lookup) = ':'`

> 01 Testing this string:Finance and Tax:Europe:Netherlands:Live
>   Programmes and Projects
>
> 02 Something:Manage programmes and projects:Asia:Nepal:Live Programmes and Projects

**Clarification**: The lines above show the structure of the data that I store in my table which represents a folder structure where each level is separated by a colon. In the above example I need find the substr of some length Y for example using the data for 02 above I find the first colon using

```
> SELECT SUBSTRING(path, 13, 1) FROM lookup WHERE *character* = ':'
```

where it matches the character ':' and this is true for the 02 entry but not 01. Now I need to return all the substr expressions in that table starting from position Y + 1 for example using

```
> SELECT SUBSTRING(path, 13 + 1, 200) FROM lookup
```

This returns

> is string:Finance and Tax:Europe:Netherlands:Live Programmes and
>   Projects
>
> Manage programmes and projects:Asia:Nepal:Live Programmes and
>   Projects

But I only want the results that are true for the first expression where the character at position 13 = ':' so in this case I would only want the second line of data to be returned.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide sample output?  Perhaps 4 or 5 rows before and after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(path, Y + 1, len(path)) -- Instead of 200 use Len() function
FROM lookup 
where SUBSTRING(path, Y, 1) = ':' -- Replace Y with position
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Spent hours on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to return everything after the first colon, wherever it sits.  Here is how you could do that:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(path, CHARINDEX(':', path) + 1, len(path)) as after_first_colon
FROM lookup
```